# Function in $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$ with geometric sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$:

1)  $\exists$ $L>0$ : $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall$ $n\ge 1$

$$|f^{(n)}(x)| \le L,$$

2) $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0, \quad \mbox{$\forall$} n\ge 1.$$

With these conditions, prove that:
$$f(x)\equiv 0, \quad  \mbox {in}\quad \mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor's theorem, one has: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall (x,y)^2\in\mathbb{R}^2,\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^k(y)}{k!}(x-y)^k\right|\leqslant\frac{L^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|x-y|^{n+1}.$$
Therefore, $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$, since $\displaystyle\frac{L^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|x-y|^{n+1}\rightarrow 0$. Hence, if $f$ is nonzero, then the set formed by its zeros has no limit point, which is a contradiction, since $\displaystyle\left\{\frac{1}{n};n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 1}\right\}$ admits $0$ as a limit point.